# Smarter justifying in OpenOffice

Tags: formatting, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer

Open a new document in OpenOffice, ensure that the default font is size 12 Times New Roman and set the alignment to justify. Now, paste or type the following (all on one line, ignore the reformatting here).

> I will ping the servers: stash.ronald.mcdonalds.com and secretstuff.steveballmersdesktop.microsoft.com.

Notice how the first line has untenably large spaces between the words in order to reach the far edge of the screen since the last domain is huge and has to wrap to the next line. (I suspect that the same might happen in MS Word, but I don't have a copy to test with.)

How can I make justify "smarter" and let it know that in this case it would be ok to split the domains on the "." as well as on spaces? Is there an alternate solution to this problem that renders a document that's a bit more appealing to the eye? Assume that the document as a whole needs to be justified, and just switching to left-align is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to use automatic hyphenation.  Even without long domains in your text, it generally makes justified text look better.  Unfortunately, your domain names won't break at the period, but have hyphens inserted instead.

To enable automatic hyphenation, select *Paragraph* from the *Format* menu, and select the *Text Flow* tab.  Under *Hyphenation*, check *Automatically*.  Note that OpenOffice's automatic hypehnation behavior is configurable so you can adjust the look if necessary:

[image: OpenOffice Hyphenation]

Comment: In this example, it actually hyphenates it at secretstuff.steve-ballmersdesktop... which is unfortunate because that's not an obviously inserted hyphen. But I think this is as close as I'm going to get without having to do the whole thing manually.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you will have to manage such a situation manually, for example by inserting optional breaks. Besides optional hyphens, there are **no-width optional breaks** available: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or Menu `Insert -> Formatting Mark -> No-width optional break`. This way, you could insert the optional breaks "preemptively".

In any case, there seems to be no "smart" solution for those cases. It's the same with long paths, maybe in combination with domains. If you can't use formatting features, for example enumerations:

> I will ping the servers:
>
> - stash.ronald.mcdonalds.com and
> - secretstuff.steveballmersdesktop.microsoft.com.

you will have to hyphenate the domain. Even with no-width breaks, there's no ideal solution: placing the break after a separating dot looks as if the sentence is finished at the end of the line, placing it before the dot makes the next line start with a dot:

```
I will ping the servers: stash.ronald.mcdonalds.
com and secretstuff.steveballmersdesktop.microsoft.com.

I will ping the servers: stash.ronald.mcdonalds
.com and secretstuff.steveballmersdesktop.microsoft.com.`
```

In certain cases, it may be required to clarify the domain and/or path explicitly, using a comment in footnotes or parentheses.